# i cant pass data from python flask api to javascript by tojson

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

i am trying to send data from my flask api to javacript by return render_template`("login.html",statef="0")` but something hapening on javascript end keeping me from correctly recieving my data

the problem is in `curr={{statef|tojson}}` i tried (()) instead of {{}} but it doesnt work, it outputs me that tojson is not defined.
here is my api code:

```
return render_template('login.html',statef="0")
```

and here is my javascript:

```
<script>
    var statef=document.getElementById("state"), curr= {{statef|tojson}}

    document.getElementById('state').innerHTML=curr
    console.log(curr);
    console.log(statef);
</script>
```

Comment: So what happens _instead_? Please share the output or full traceback of the error you see. What is the _expected_ output?

Comment: nothing happens, it just doesnt output the result i want which is outputing 0 in the console

Comment: Look in your browser tools. **What is the output of the template**? Don't rely on what is being executed by the browser, you could have other errors that obscure matters. You want to look at this as *pure text generating*. Executing the text as JavaScript code comes next.

Comment: You can always use `curl` to get *just* the Javascript template output, too.

Comment: Why are you using `tojson`? What is the output of `{{statef}}` in the javascript?

Comment: @arsho this supposed the way to recieve the variable from python and convert it to a form that javascript understand

Comment: my code doesnt accept the idea of double curly product in first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Example of using `tojson` filter in flask template to parse JSON

You can pass data from Flask to Javascript and read it as JSON using the `tojson` filter in Flask template [(documentation of `tojson` filter in Flask template)](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#standard-filters) :

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_login():
    statef_data = {
        "email": "demo@example.com",
        "name": "Alice"
    }
    return render_template('login.html', statef=statef_data)
```

`login.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="state">

  </div>
<script>
    var curr= {{ statef|tojson }};
    console.log(curr);
    console.log(typeof(curr));
    document.getElementById('state').innerHTML=curr["email"] + "<br>"+curr["name"];
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image: tojson]

Console log:

```
{email: 'demo@example.com', name: 'Alice'}
login:14 object
```

References:

- [Documentation of `tojson` filter in Flask template](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#standard-filters)

Comment: i tried that already but the problem in `var curr= {{ statef|tojson }};` speciffecclly in the double curly braces, the code doesnt accept them for a reason

Comment: if i run it this error pops up: `TypeError: Object of type Undefined is not JSON serializable`

Comment: after a lot of trials clearly the problem is from tojson, it recieves an undefined type from python although i wrote the same things you wrote exactly

Comment: I think there might be some typo or something else that gave you the undefined type. I have double checked the code listed in this answer and it is running properly. The screenshot proves it.

Comment: i opened a new projectt and copy pasted your code as is just to check that i am not going crazy and the i got the same error `TypeError: Object of type Undefined is not JSON serializable`

Comment: I think I'm running into the same problem, I am getting SyntaxError with the curly braces as well... Any progress?