# Unexpected token '{' When I try to pass data from Flask to Javascript

Tags: javascript, flask

Hi I am developing an app using Flask.
From a page, I would like catch a variable in my Javascript.

**Flask**

```
@Cov19_msc.route("/page2", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def page2():
    user_data = {
        "email": "user_mail",
        "name": "John"
    }
    return render_template("/page2.html", user_data=user_data)
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    var u_data= {{ user_data|tojson }};
    console.log(u_data);
});
```

Unfortunately I get immediatly this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' (at test.js:3:18)
```

However, I read that this solution should works like in this post:
[i cant pass data from python flask api to javascript by tojson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74583764/i-cant-pass-data-from-python-flask-api-to-javascript-by-tojson)

Could you please tell me where I am wrong?

**EDIT 1:**

The HTML part of the app is managed using jinja2

**html_template.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/my_style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
     <div>
        <div class="container-fluid" id="whole_screen">
             
             {% block content %}

             {% endblock %}

         </div>
    </div>
    <script type=text/javascript src="{{  url_for('static', filename='js/test.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**page2.html**

```
{% extends "html_template.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div>
    <p>{{user_data}}</p>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

The test.js is called as a script in the body of the html template.
The html template is used by the page2.html. For this reason, I thought that the test.js runs also in the page2.

Although it is weird for me, I saw the usage of the {{ }} in flask apps with javascript and jinja. Some examples are posted on Stackoverflow (I reposted only one of them in this question)

Comment: `test.js` is not being parsed by flask, so the value of u_data is not changed.

Comment: Thanks James for your answer. Unfortunately, I am new to using Javascript and I don't understand 100% your suggestion. Do you mean that because test.js is not parsed by flask I got the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' (at test.js:3:18) ?

Comment: It's more about Jinja, not exactly flask. How is that JS included into the `page2.html` template? `<script src ...>` or `{% include ... %}`? I suspect the former and recommend the latter.

Comment: I edited my question adding the html part. I put the script's code section in the html template. But I did not use the `include`. How can I use `include` in my html template?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think I can answer to the main part of my question. The solution I found is from the HTML side using Jinja.

I modified the page2 code in this way:

**page2.html**

```
{% extends "general_layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div>
    <p>{{user_data}}</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var user_data='{{ user_data|tojson }}'
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

The output in the console is:

[image]

I think that `var user_data='{{ user_data|tojson }}'` let be `user_data` available for the javascript because `user_data` is created into the `<script>` tag but fetching the variable from jinja (if I am right).

I did not tried the jp-jee suggestion but I want to.

Answer (score 0):

The double bracket `{{` in javasscript code means nothing, its complaining about the second curly bracket.

You need to change this line `var u_data= {{ user_data|tojson }};` or remove it altogether.  Is not `user_data` already in JSON format?

EDIT:

Is Flask supposed to interpret that for JS before serving the page?  Is this JS in a separate file?  Perhaps it should be in the Flask template.

The link you gave the JS is in the page's template not a separate file.

Comment: Yes m.e.conroy I put the script in an external file named test.js. Could you please have a look of my EDIT 1 and advise for errors in passing the external test.js? About your suggestions for fixing the code, if I remove the `|tojson`  the error is still `Unexpected token '{'`. Then if I remove the first couple of brackets leaving `var u_data= {user_data};` the error is `Uncaught ReferenceError: user_data is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised by JavaScript because it sees `{{ user_data|tojson }}`, which is not a valid JS statement.

Here is what happens: You send `page2.html` through flask's `render_template` function which processes it as expected. All your Jinja statements are replaced by the respective value. The rendered HTML will then contain:

```
<script type=text/javascript src="/your/static/path/js/test.js"></script>
```

When the page is loaded, the browser requests the file from the given static path. The server will deliver the file as-is.

To solve this, you can include the script directly into your template using

```
{% include "js/test.js" %}
```

You might want to move the JS file from your static folder to a more convenient place.
When `page2.html` is processed by Jinja, the content of `test.js` will be processed aswell and embedded in the resulting HTML. The browser will not request the file separately.
This can be a disadvantage for large JS files because the browser will not be able to cache it and instead, the content must be transferred with every request.

Alternatively, you could implement a specific route for these cases which serves your "static" files (they are not, since the content is dynamic) after passing them to `render_template()`. Pitfall: You need to prevent browsers from caching the file.